# How do I change the value of an input text field based on if a checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, switch-statement

Basically I have an email field, then a checkbox under it. If it's checked i want it to change the value of the email address field to something like originalemailATgmail.com@mydomain.com then if it's unchecked I want it to display "originalemail@gmail.com" that it started with.  I'm having a problem switching back to the original email value after changing it to "derrrr"

```
[html]

<input type="email" name="email_address" value="originalemail@gmail.com" id="email_addressez">
<input type="checkbox" name="post_date_email" value="post_date_email" id="post_date_email" onclick="postDateEmail(document.getElementById(&quot;email_addressez&quot;).value)">
function postDateEmail(email){
var emailchecked=document.getElementById("post_date_email").checked;
var emailsub = "derrrrrr";
var originalemail = email;
alert("email is "+email+" checked is "+emailchecked);
if(emailchecked=true){
    //var email=document.getElementById("email_addressez").value;
    alert("in if, email is " + email + " checked is "+emailchecked);
    document.getElementById("email_addressez").value = emailsub;
}else{
    alert("else" + email + " checked is "+emailchecked);
    document.getElementById("email_addressez").value = email;
    }
}

[/html]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working sample of what you are trying to do.
And notably, when writing conditional operation like `if else` statements.
You use `==` or `===` depending on what you want.

In your case, using `=` is an assignment operator so your `if` statement will not work at all.

Below is a simplified version using ternary operators `?` and `:`

```js
function postDateEmail() {
  var checked = document.getElementById('post_date_email').checked;
  document.getElementById('email_addressez').value = 'originalemail' + (checked ? 'AT' : '') + '@gmail.com';
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email_address" value="originalemail@gmail.com" id="email_addressez">
<input type="checkbox" name="post_date_email" value="post_date_email" id="post_date_email" onclick="postDateEmail()">
```

Answer (score 0):

ended up modifying your code to this:

```
var checked = document.getElementById('post_date_email').checked;
var originalemail = <?php echo(json_encode($email)); ?>;
var postDateEmailAddy = originalemail.replace("@", "AT");
var postDateEmailAddy = postDateEmailAddy.replace(".com", ".com@mydomain.com");
//alert(postDateEmailAddy);
document.getElementById('email_addressez').value = (checked ? postDateEmailAddy : originalemail);
```

where $email is defined elsewhere in the php.